# Can I have "Unknown" set as the SkypeOut call identification?

Tags: caller-id, skype-out

I know when i call from SkypeOut, people receiving the call see SkypeOut number. What i want is to see them **"Unknown"** so they will have no idea where call might be coming from. Is this possible?

Also when i call from SkypeOut, the number that recipient sees is **random generated number** or static number?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

> Yes, just disable caller ID in your account page/SKYPEOUT number

http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=113832

Comment: Boris_yo, was this what you were looking for?

Comment: I don't have SkypeOut caller ID. I just have weird SkypeOut number that only shows that call may be coming from Skype as a source. What i want is to disable any number showing on recipient's phone when i call him so he would only see "Unknown".

Comment: This setting should do that.

Comment: I cannot find option to disable. This is what i see: **http://i.imm.io/6596.png**

You can zoom in.

Comment: Set up caller identification.

Comment: Not that won't work. Skype representative told me that it is not possible to hide Skype's ID, sometimes receiver will see numbers and sometimes won't see anything.

Comment: What the description says there is what I am assuming it will do. In addition, other people have had this work for them. I don't think it can hurt to try it. And if they told you it was impossible, why did you even bother to ask the question?

Comment: They told me after i got your last answer.

Comment: So what do you think that option does?

Comment: That options disables caller ID that you setup as your phone number you want recipient to return call. After that, your calls will be identified as Skype numbers or Unknown depending on carrier.